# $E[X]$ finite iff $\sum\limits_{n} P(X>an)$ converges

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show that:

$$\sum\limits_{n \in N } P(X>an) < \infty\ \text{for some}\ a > 0 \Rightarrow E[X] < \infty \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n \in N } P(X>an) < \infty\ \text{for every}\ a > 0.$$

We have an unknown probability space ($\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$, where $\mathbb F$ is a sigma-algebra, and $P:\mathbb F \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a probability measure, $X$ is a $\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable random variable and $E[X]$ is the expectation of the variable $X$.

I've been working through past exam papers, and am stuck on this. Would appreciate a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove the first implication.

Let's take $a>0$ such that $\sum_{n \in N } P(X>an) < \infty$.

First of all, $P(X>an)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}P(X\in(an,a(n+1)])$. Hence, we write
$\infty>\sum_{n \in N } P(X>an) = \sum_{n \in N } \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} P(X\in(ak,a(k+1)])$. By [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem) we can change the order of summation. We arrive at

$\sum_{k \in N } \sum_{n=0}^{k} P(X\in(ak,a(k+1)])=\sum_{k \in N }  (k+1) P(X\in(ak,a(k+1)])$.

If $d\mu(x)$ represents our probability measure (i.e. $P(X\in A)=\int_{x\in A} d\mu(x)$), then we can continue

$ \sum_{k \in N }  (k+1) P(X\in(ak,a(k+1)]) = \frac {1}{a}\sum_{k \in N }  a(k+1) \int_{(ak,a(k+1)]}d\mu$
$\ge \frac {1}{a}\sum_{k \in N }   \int_{x\in (ak,a(k+1)]}xd\mu(x)=\frac {1}{a}    \int_{x>0}xd\mu(x)\ge \frac {1}{a}E[X]$ by definition. In other words, $E[X]<\infty$. Note that there can still be $E[X]=-\infty$.

In order to prove the second implication, a little modification of this trick is enough.

Comment: Could you hint as to the modification for the follow up?

Comment: Just let a $\in \mathbb{R}$ and then note E[X] < $\infty \Rightarrow E[X]/a < \infty$? And then proceed to show that all the other statements, in the opposite direction, are also $\leq \infty$?

Comment: Okay. hmm.. that didnt work.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Let's start with the followin statement: $E[X]<\infty\iff E[|X|]<\infty$. It should be in your course.

Then we write $\sum_{n\ge 0}P(X>an)\le \sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an) = \sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k\ge n}P(X\in (ak,ak+a]) =  \frac{1}{a}\sum_{k\ge 1}akP(X\in (ak,ak+a]) = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{k\ge 1}ak\int_{x\in (ak,ak+a]}d\mu(x)\le \frac{1}{a}\sum_{k\ge 1} \int_{x\in (ak,ak+a]}x d\mu(x) = \frac{1}{a}\int_{a}^\infty x d\mu(x) \le \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^\infty x d\mu(x)\le \frac{1}{a}\int_{\mathbb R}  |x| d\mu(x)=\frac{1}{a}E[|X|]<\infty$

Comment: Thanks @Tzakrevskiy 
Why do we have that first inequality?: 
$\sum_{n\ge 0}P(X>an)\le \sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an) $

Comment: Isn't it the case that: 
$\sum_{n\ge 0}P(X>an) = P(X>0) + \sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an) \ge \sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an)$

Comment: @Sandra You are right, of course $\sum_{n\ge 0}P(X>an)\le \sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an)$. So, to correct my proof you start with $\sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an)$, you conduct all the reasoning just the same until you arrive at $\sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an)\le \frac{1}{a}E[|X|]<\infty$, and then say that $\sum_{n\ge 0}P(X>an)=P(X>0)+\sum_{n\ge 1}P(X>an)\le \frac{1}{a}E[|X|]+P(X>0)<\infty$.

Comment: ahha! Thanks. that makes sense. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: for $X>0$,
$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty x f(x) \mathrm d x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{na}^{(n+1)a} x f(x) \mathrm d x$$

Can you bound these integrals in terms of integrals of $f$? What can you do with the factors?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try to integrate the pointwise inequality $X\leqslant a\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{X\gt an}$ to get one implication. For the other implication, try to find a similar pointwise inequality, only reversed.

**Edit:** Consider $a\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{X\gt an}$ (note that the sum is starting at $n=1$, not $n=0$), can you compare it to $X$?

Comment: Hi @Did could you please give an idea for the other implication?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $