# Show that $\frac{1}{n}X_n\to 0\mbox{ a.e.}$

Tags: probability-theory

> > Show that for any sequence $(X_n)$ of identically distributed integrable random variables it is 
> >     $$
> > \frac{1}{n}X_n\to 0\text{ a.e.}
> > $$

Hello! I am missing an idea...

I have to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\left\{\frac{1}{n}X_n\not\to 0\right\})=0.
$$
I do not know which tool I need to apply:

- weak law of large numers?
- strong law of large numbers?
- Ergoden?

Maybe you can give me a hint...

I am sorry that I cannot give more own ideas yet.

Comment: Idea: Borel-Cantelli lemma for the events $A_n=[|X_n|\geqslant n\varepsilon]$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389759/ex-finite-iff-sum-limits-n-pxan-converges

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The inequality

$$\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} 1_{\{|X| \geq n\}} \leq |X|$$

entails

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq n) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|) \tag{1}$$

*(Thanks to @ByronSchmuland for the suggestion of this simplification.)* Use this in order to prove

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{X_n}{n} \right| > \varepsilon \right) < \infty.$$

Now apply Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: It all starts with the problem, that I do not see why it is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X\rvert\geq n)\leq E(\lvert X\rvert)$. I only see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X\rvert\geq n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(1_{\lvert X\rvert\geq n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int 1_{\lvert X\rvert\geq n}\, d\mu$.

Comment: resp. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E(1_{\lvert X\rvert\geq n})\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(1_{\lvert X\rvert\geq n}\lvert X\rvert)$.

Comment: @math12 I have added the proof of the inequality.

Comment: Sorry I do not come along with that. Isn't there a more direct way to show, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon)<\infty$?

Comment: The inequality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{(|X|\geq n)} \leq |X|$ holds pointwise. Now take expectations.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Nice way to prove the inequality. Much more easier, indeed. I have added your idea to my answer; I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @saz No problem! It is not my idea, it is pretty standard.

Comment: I post my proof based on your answer below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my proof based on your help.** Please tell me if it is ok.

Consider any $\varepsilon>0$.

Define $Y:=\frac{\lvert X_1\rvert}{\varepsilon}$.
$$
A_m:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: m\leq Y(\omega)<m+1\right\}, m\geq 1.
$$

Consider an arbitrary fixed $\omega\in\Omega$. Then $Y(\omega)\in A_m$ for a $m\geq 1$.

Then it is
$$
Y(\omega)\geq \sum_{n=1}^m 1_{\left\{Y>n\right\}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{Y>n\right\}}.
$$
Because $\omega$ was chosen arbitrarily, this is for any $\omega\in\Omega$.
From this it follows
$$
\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}(Y)\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(1_{\left\{Y>n\right\}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\left\{Y>n\right\})
$$
And (because of the integrability of $X_1$) it is
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\Omega}\lvert X_1\rvert\, d\mathbb{P}<\infty.
$$

Define
$$
M_n:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}.
$$

From what is shown above, it follows from Borel-Cantelli, that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}M_n)=\mathbb{P}(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \omega\in M_n\text{ for infinite many }n\right\})=0.
$$
Because of
$$
N:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \frac{1}{n}X_n(\omega)\not\to 0\right\}\subset\limsup_{n\to\infty}M_n,
$$
it follows
$$
\mathbb{P}(N)\leq\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}M_n)=0\Rightarrow\mathbb{P}(N)=0.
$$

So $\frac{1}{n}X_n\to 0\text{ a.e.}~~\diamond$

Comment: Instead of $$Y(\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^m 1_{\{Y>n\}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y>n\}}$$ it should read $$Y(\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^m 1_{\{Y \geq n\}}(\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y \geq n\}}(\omega).$$ (Otherwise the inequality does not hold for any $\omega \in A_m$ such that $Y(\omega)=m$.)